# How to draw a path of lowest numbers through the matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, graph, topology

so I am trying to draw a path that follows the lowest numbers of this matrix as shown in the image.

[image]

something like this:

[image]

I know that there is matplotlib for drawing graphs based on x and y values but how would I draw a path like this based on the numbers of the matrix?

Any idea or a comment would be much appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First create a function to find the path you want the arrows to follow

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

# example matrix
matrix = np.array([[11, 3, 5], [2, 9, 4], [3, 1, 6]])

def find_path(matrix):
  path = []
  values = [val for row in matrix for val in row]
  values.sort()
  for value in values:
    path.append(value)
  return path

path = find_path(matrix)
```

Now draw the matrix and the path with the arrows

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(matrix)

coordinates = defaultdict(list)

# search for each value in the matrix and get the coordinates of the value. also print the number on the matrix
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j] in path:
            ax.text(j, i, matrix[i][j], ha='center', va='center', color='white')
            coordinates[matrix[i][j]].append((j, i))

# for each pair of adjacent values in the path, draw arrow from first coordinate to the next
for val, next_val in zip(path, path[1:]):
    for coord in coordinates[val]:
        for other_coord in coordinates[next_val]:
            ax.arrow(coord[0], coord[1], other_coord[0] - coord[0], other_coord[1] - coord[1], width=0.05)

plt.show()
```